# How to run tests under suite in Protractor

Tags: protractor, suite

How do I run suites in protractor. Here is my config file:

```
exports.config = {
       seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

       suites:
       {
         one: ['test.js'],
         two: ['homePageSpec.js']
       },

       onPrepare: function () {
           browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1180, 900);

       },
   }
```

I tried protractor ProtractorConf.js --suite one

Comment: And what exception did you get?

Comment: I get the following error------$ protractor ProtractorConf.js --suite one
[11:38:36] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[11:38:36] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file ProtractorConf.js
[11:38:36] E/configParser - /Users/sup/Documents/ProFirstTest/ProtractorConf.js:9
       onPrepare: function () {
       ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: The command `protractor ProtractorConf.js --suite one` is correct but you have syntax error in your onprepare function.

Comment: Try to run it without `onPrepare` method, because I'm not sure why exactly this error occurs.

Comment: the syntax was wrong! thanks @FCin

Comment: It was the square brackets that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the square brackets and it worked. like:

```
suites:
       {
         one: 'test.js',
         two: 'homePageSpec.js'
       },
```